# Keep 'Online' and 'Offline' Status in Android like Facebook

Tags: c#, android, facebook

I want to show `Online` and `Offline` status of user in `Android` application. Right now, I am calling `Service` at every 3 minutes to send data to `Windows Server` about to notify that that user is `Online`.
At `Server` side, I am using `Scheduler` which fires at every 2 minutes and check last user 'Online' status timing. If it is `>4 minutes` then it marks user as `Offline`. But, It takes my `VPS Windows Server` down sometimes and use lots of `Bandwidth`.
So, I am looking for more efficient solution.
I want this samething in `C# Web Application` also.

Comment: How do you define being online or offline? If a user leaves your application, is he/she considered offline immediately?

Comment: @Endor, right now for immediately nt possible. if user leave app means service will be destroy. so now, it wont send data to server anymore. and server scheduler is checking all users constantly at every 2 minutes, so if server finds time difference more than 4 minutes then that time that user will be consider as offline.

Comment: Try to use socket connection, then you can track real-time if socket is connected you are online, if socket is disconnected - offline. You can connect/disconnect socket in your `Activity`  `onStart()` `onStop()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: @Romadja, i have checked socket and found that more requests are possible. I am looking for many (android) to one (server) request.

Comment: So, what's the problem? You can store a list of socket connections on the server side.

Comment: @Romadja, i have never used socket. can u give me any sample ?

Comment: I recommend to use `socket.io` implementation of the socket, cause it simple to use and integrate. So there is http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/ a C# socket.io client, and there is https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client  a socket.io client for Java/Android.

Comment: @Romadja, thank you. let me check it.